# Child div being set to 100% of window, not of parent

Tags: html, css

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/korokriver/

It's been a long night. I'm having issues the grey metallic div on this page. I want the height to be 100% of the content. When I set it, it is set as 100% of the window height and falls all over the bottom of the page.

I have set 100% height on html, body, and every div leading to this one (site, copy, content, metals)

I should clarify, I explained that badly.

I want the grey child div to be the height of the site, and the height of the parent div. Not the height of it's content.

It's also happening with the other pages, though a different div.

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/korokriver/?page=geologicalconsultants

Comment: Is `height: auto` or not setting the height at all what you want?

Comment: As a note: `height:100%` is always set/referenced to the next parent element that has a position set.

Comment: so if I set the position of the site div to position:relative; top:0; it may work?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `overflow:hidden` on `#content`. That should do it.

Comment: Some pages have too much content that would need to overflow

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [something like this](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/three-liquid/)?

Comment: Yes, only that fits vertically as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the div to wrap to its contents:

Remove `height:100%;` this is currently setting it to be 100% of the window.

By default divs wrap to their content unless floating child elements are not cleared properly, so there should be no need to set a height.

You could use jQuery to set the height of the child to the height of the parent like so.

```
$('#child').height($('#parent').height());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXc3P/

Comment: If you refer to the content on the bottom - I thought that too, but it's not within the `<div>`. It's in a separate table.